# How can I use the Newton-Raphson Method to solve nonlinear Differential Equations in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose  we want to solve y'+y^2=1,y(0)=0,0⩽x⩽1 by using the Newton-Raphson method which usually used to solve the nonlinear algebraic equation by:

xn=xn−1− f(xn−1)/ f′(xn−1);

How can we do it for ODE?

Comment: There is an exact solution `y=1`. What is the method for?

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry I correct the initial condition y(0)=0; I just want to know how can we apply Newton-Raphson method to nonlinear ODE in general. I was  given this example just to make it clear to me for simple example...thanks

Comment: Exact solution is `y[x]=Tanh[x]`

Comment: Dear Ulrich, yes I know, but my question to implement the Newton-Raphson method for nonlinear ODE as you know practical problem does not has an exact solution.

Comment: `NDSolve` accommodates a variety of ODE solution algorithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of using the method

```
y[0] = 1; dx = 1/100; 
f[y_] := 2*y^2 - y^3 + 10*Cos[2*y] - 2*Sin[3*y]; a = 1/2;
sol = Table[{i*dx, 
    y[i] = y1 /. 
      FindRoot[(y1 - y[i - 1])/dx + (a*f[y1] + (1 - a)*f[y[i - 1]]) ==
         0, {y1, y[i - 1]}]}, {i, 1, 100}];
```

Here we call `FindRoot[]`,and it uses Newton's method as default.
Compare with another numerical method

```
eq = ys'[x] + f[ys[x]] == 0;
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{eq, ys[0] == 1}, ys, {x, 0, 1}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]

Show[Plot[sol1[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"a=", a*1.}], PlotStyle -> Red], ListPlot[sol]]
```

[image: fig1]

Use `FixedPointList[]` to find the root by the Newton method, then the code for solving a differential equation $y'+y^2-1=0,y(0)=0$ is

```
newtonsMethodList[f_, x0_, n_] := 
 With[{iter = # - f[#]/D[f[#], #]}, FixedPointList[iter &, x0, n]]
dx = 1/100; a = .5; x[0] = 0; y[0] = 0; F[y_] := y^2 - 1

Do[f[y1_] := (y1 - y[i - 1])/dx + (a*F[y1] + (1 - a)*F[y[i - 1]]); 
 x[i] = dx*i; 
 y[i] = Last[newtonsMethodList[f, y[i - 1], 30]];, {i, 1, 100}]

Show[Plot[Tanh[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Orange], 
 ListPlot[Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, 100}]]]
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: Dear Alex, thanks, but in above is differential equation you solved?

Comment: @user62716 The differential equation `y'[x]+2*y[x]^2 - y[x]^3 + 10*Cos[2*y[x]] - 2*Sin[3*y[x]] ==0` is solved. I specifically chose a nonlinear function when integrating which some methods fail.

Comment: Hi Alex, your code is confuse me, can we modify the below code for nonlinear ode( I found it in current web.):f[x_] := x^2 - 2*x + 1

newtonsMethodList[f_, x0_, n_] := 
 With[{iter = # - f[#]/D[f[#], #]}, FixedPointList[iter &, x0, n]] 

x = newtonsMethodList[f, 0.5, 10]

{0.5, 0.75, 0.875, 0.9375, 0.96875, 0.984375, 0.992188, 0.996094, \
0.998047, 0.999023, 0.999512}

f[x]

{0.25, 0.0625, 0.015625, 0.00390625, 0.000976563, 0.000244141, \
0.0000610352, 0.0000152588, 3.8147*10^-6, 9.53674*10^-7, 
 2.38419*10^-7}

Comment: Do you want to adapt the method of solving algebraic equations to solve differential equations? There are many algorithms. I showed one that uses the Newton method by calling  'FindRoot[]'. But you want to use `FixedPointList`?

Comment: Dear Alex, as you can see before fixedpointlist the N-R method form already written:newtonsMethodList[f_, x0_, n_] := 
 With[{iter = # - f[#]/D[f[#], #]}, FixedPointList[iter &, x0, n]] ; can we do it to my original nonlinear ODE?

Comment: Waiting your response Alex...Thanks

Comment: @user62716 see update.

Comment: Dear Alex, thank you very much, could you please tell what is a? and more details about:Do[f[y1_] := (y1 - y[i - 1])/dx + (a*F[y1] + (1 - a)*F[y[i - 1]]); 
 x[i] = dx*i; 
 y[i] = Last[newtonsMethodList[f, y[i - 1], 30]];, {i, 1, 10}]

Comment: @user62716 `a` is a parameter of the numerical method, `0<=a<=1`.  For this method, it is optimal to take `a=1/2`.  In the loop, we define a function`f[]` to calculate the root, which is the solution to the equation in one step. Total steps 100.

Comment: Thank you Alex you answered the first part, what                       about the second paper  Do[f[y1_] := (y1 - y[i - 1])/dx + (aF[y1] + (1 - a)*F[y[i - 1]]); x[i] = dxi; y[i] = Last[newtonsMethodList[f, y[i - 1], 30]];, {i, 1, 10}] 

 please more details, which method? exactly this part:Do[f[y1_] := (y1 - y[i - 1])/dx + (a*F[y1] + (1 - a)*F[y[i - 1]]); 
 x[i] = dx*I???

Comment: @user62716 For `a =0` we have an explicit Euler, for `a=1` there is an implicit Euler, and for `a=1/2` it is Newton–Cotes rule.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex you solved my problem.

Comment: @user62716 You're welcome!

Comment: In case `a = 1/2`, the method is also known as Crank-Nicolson method.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You're right. For the PDE this is called Crank–Nicolson method.

Answer (score 0):

What about an iterative approach which uses Newton method?

Series of righthand side of ode near y[t]=y0[t]  `y'[t]=1-y[t]^2~1+y0[t]^2-2 y0[t] y[t]

The approximative ode is linear. Iterative solution gives a very good approximation

```
NestList[NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == 1 + #^2 - 2 # y[t], y[0] == 0},y[t], {t, 0, 1}] &, 0, 3]
Show[Plot[% , {t, 0, 1}],Plot[Tanh[t] , {t, 0, 1},PlotStyle->Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Ulrich, thanks I know NDsolve, but still looking for N-R code..

Comment: I didn't get the basic purpose of your question. What is the relation between the Newton iteration `xn==...` and the ode you gave as an example?

Comment: Dear Ulrich, I want to solve nonlinear differential equation by Newton-Raphson methid which is usually used to solve nonlinear algebraic equation...Thanks

Comment: That's clear, but you didn't tell how you want to apply the method. If you want a method like the one   Trounev presented in his  answer , you take an implicit  method (Gauss, midpoint, ???) and try to solve it with Newton-Raphson?

Comment: Dear Ulrich, I want it as we when solve the nonlinear algebraic equation:ClearAll["Global`*"]

f[x_] := x^2 - 2*x + 1

newtonsMethodList[f_, x0_, n_] := 
 With[{iter = # - f[#]/D[f[#], #]}, FixedPointList[iter &, x0, n]] 

x = newtonsMethodList[f, 0.5, 10]

{0.5, 0.75, 0.875, 0.9375, 0.96875, 0.984375, 0.992188, 0.996094, \
0.998047, 0.999023, 0.999512}

f[x]

{0.25, 0.0625, 0.015625, 0.00390625, 0.000976563, 0.000244141, \
0.0000610352, 0.0000152588, 3.8147*10^-6, 9.53674*10^-7, 
 2.38419*10^-7}

Comment: Ok you have a procedure to solve the equation `f[y]==0`, I didn't see the context with the ode `y'[y]== 1-y[x]^2`

Comment: Yes, this my main question!

Comment: But you should have a fundamental idea to restrict the unknown ode-solver  Newton-Raphson!

Comment: Thanks Ulrich for your time, I think it is out of your interest....Best regards